# Header CSS inconsistencies across browsers

Tags: html, css

The header of my website renders differently in Firefox and Chrome, even though the CSS is the same. Specifically, here's how it appears:

[image]

I.e. the header in Firefox has some extra padding on top that I haven't intended. The design in the extra padding is a background image in the body. I have not set any extra margin on the header at all. My header's CSS code is:

```
.header h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
```

And in the HTML, I simply have:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1> Fast Internet </h1>
```

Comment: are you closing the div tag?

Comment: Learn about CSS reset - this may be some default browser styling

Comment: @EugeneXa  How is CSS reset related to this problem ?

Comment: @c-smile when you have two standard-compliant browsers behaving differently, most likely cause is CSS you didn't write but that came as a browser default

Comment: @EugeneXa: that's actually quite interesting. Could you include that as an answer (with an illustrative example)? I'm looking at it, and yours might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

That's [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) in effect. Add `margin-top:0;` to your `h1` rule:

```
.header h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  ...
}
```

By default `h1` has `margin-top/bottom:1em` or so and that margin-top gets propagated into margin-top of its container (`<div.header>` here).